# Member Expression cannot convert to object from nullable decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-expressions

I am working on an MVC project and would like to pass the Html.TextboxFor method the name of a property.  This is my viewmodel

```
public class RuleViewModel<T> where T : class, IValidatableObject
{
    private T _rule;
    public T RuleModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _rule
                ?? (_rule = Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        }
    }

    public RuleMetadata Metadata { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<RuleViewModel<T>, Object>> GetParameterByName(PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        var fieldName = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RuleViewModel<T>), "x");
        var fieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Property(fieldName, "RuleModel"), pi.Name);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<RuleViewModel<T>, Object>>(fieldExpression, fieldName);
        return exp;
    }

}
```

Then in the view I do this

```
  @foreach (var prop in Model.RuleModel.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var result = Model.Metadata.Columns.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ColumnName == prop.Name);
        if (result != null)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model.GetParameterByName(prop))
            </td>
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the property is of type decimal?, I get a cannot convert nullable decimal to object error.  I looked around and found that you can use Expression.Convert to fix this but when I do that I get an error on the view

Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Any help would be appreciated.  This is a proof of concept project that I'm working on and without this piece it is dead in the water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't just use `object` as `TProperty` when calling `TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>()`.  It expects a lambda expression of the form `Func<TModel, TProperty>`, and the variance rules of C# are such that a `Func<TModel, decimal?>` is not assignment compatible with `Func<TModel, object>`.  You also can't simply use `Convert()`, because the MVC internals won't accept a lambda whose body is a `Convert` expression.

What you *can* do is use dynamic binding to invoke `TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>()` with the correct type arguments:

```
public Expression GetParameterByName(PropertyInfo pi)
{
    var fieldName = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RuleViewModel<T>), "x");
    var fieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(
        Expression.Property(fieldName, "RuleModel"),
        pi.Name);
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(
        typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(RuleViewModel<T>), fieldExpression.Type),
        fieldExpression,
        fieldName);
    return exp;
}

// ...

@InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(Html, (dynamic)Model.GetParameterByName(prop))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I do this I get a runtime error saying     no applicable method named 'TextBoxFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched.  Any ideas?  I was able to get aruond this whole issue by defining four or five different GetParameter methods with each using a different return type, and using conditional statements in the view which will work for proof of concept, but man is it ugly.

Comment: What if you invoke `TextBoxFor()` statically?  See if this works: `@InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(Html, (dynamic)Model.GetParameterByName(prop))`

Comment: Mark you are a beautiful man. That did the trick. Thank you so much.