# Checkbox For using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to call:

```
InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor(h, (dynamic)GetBoolParameterByName(model, propInfo));
```

Here is my attempt at the expression side.

```
public Expression GetBoolParameterByName(T source, PropertyInfo pi)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
            Expression body = param;
            typeof (Nullable<>).GetMethod("GetValueOrDefault", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, Type.DefaultBinder,
                new Type[] {typeof (bool)}, null);

            var func = typeof(Nullable<bool>).GetMethod("GetValueOrDefault", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, Type.DefaultBinder,
                new Type[] { typeof(bool) }, null);
            body = MethodCallExpression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(body, pi.Name), func, Expression.Constant(false));
            return Expression.Lambda(body, param);  
        }
```

I figured this would work because CheckboxFor takes an expression of  `Func<T,bool>` but I keep getting

`'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.'`

Can anyone explain what this error is an what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out, CheckBoxFor does not accept p.prop.GetValueOrDefault() you must do p=>p.prop.Value. although you have to make sure to override the name and ID attributes on the element because you will get prop.Value instead of prop

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        Expression body = param;
        body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.PropertyOrField(body, pi.Name), pi.PropertyType.GetMember("Value").First());
        return Expression.Lambda(body, param);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in `GetBoolParameterByName` method. The only possible problem may be that you pass a `PropertyInfo` of a property which is not of type `bool?` (such as ID) to it.

Comment: Alas I figured out that p=>p.prop.GetValueOrDefault() doesn't actually work I need to do p=>p.prop.Value I'm just not sure how to do this, my attempt was    body =  Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.PropertyOrField(body, pi.Name), "Value"); but that does not seem to work